# Electron crashes when requiring sqlite3 native module in forked process

Tags: node.js, electron

I'm trying to use sqlite3 module in a child process with electron, but I get error of undefined symbol. Also, the error happens only when I run the program from electron's node.js, but when I run the program from usual node.js everything works fine. I think the problem may be related to 'nativeness' of sqlite3 module, and I tried `electron-rebuild`, `npm --build-from-source`, they didn't help.

main.js:

```
const { fork } = require('child_process');
fork('fork');
```

fork.js:

```
const sqlite3 = require('sqlite3');
```

package.json:

```
{
  "name": "bugreproduce_sqlite",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "main.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "sqlite3": "^4.0.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "electron": "^3.0.5"
  }
}
```

output:

```
> ./node_modules/electron/dist/electron .
/home/myuser/Programming/javascript/bugreproduce_sqlite/node_modules/electron/dist/electron: symbol lookup error: /home/myuser/Programming/javascript/bugreproduce_sqlite/node_modules/sqlite3/lib/binding/node-v64-linux-x64/node_sqlite3.node: undefined symbol: _ZN2v816FunctionTemplate3NewEPNS_7IsolateEPFvRKNS_20FunctionCallbackInfoINS_5ValueEEEENS_5LocalIS4_EENSA_INS_9SignatureEEEiNS_19ConstructorBehaviorENS_14SideEffectTypeE
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the root problem. 
Here is the relevant [issue](https://github.com/mapbox/node-pre-gyp/issues/278) and [pull request 1](https://github.com/mapbox/node-pre-gyp/pull/279), [pull request 2](https://github.com/mapbox/node-pre-gyp/pull/343) on GitHub.

My steps to temporarily fixing the problem were:

- Clone node-pre-gyp git repository
- `checkout` to the version sqlite3 wants(0.10.3 at the moment)
- Apply patch from the second pull request
- Install this patched node-pre-gyp via `npm install ../path/to/patched/node-pre-gyp` from the main project folder
- `npm i --build-from-source sqlite3`(not sure this command is needed) and `./node_modules/.bin/electron-rebuild` from the main project folder (I installed electron-rebuild)
- call `fork` with electron version set, like this:

  `fork('fork', [], {
      env: {
          ELECTRON_VERSION: "3.0.5"
      }});`

This is a hack, but it seems to work. Hope the problem will be fixed in upstream.

edited: fixed pull request link (I used the second pull request, not the first)

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the same problem by:

1. Updating Electron to v6 Beta. Version 6 has the needed feature of [adding `process.versions.electron` to get the Electron version in forked processes](https://github.com/electron/electron/pull/16450).
2. Using [electron-builder](https://github.com/electron-userland/electron-builder)'s "install-app-deps" command as a postinstall script. That means putting `"postinstall": "electron-builder install-app-deps"` in my npm scripts in package.json.

As to *why* the issue happens:

- node-sqlite3's main module uses node-pre-gyp to figure out which compiled sqlite binary to require
- node-pre-gyp tries to detect the process runtime to return the path to the correct binary for the process/platform.
- node-pre-gyp's detection function (`get_process_runtime` in versioning.js) looks at `process.versions.electron` to see if the process is an Electron process. Otherwise it assumes a Node process.
- Since `process.versions.electron` was not implemented in my version of Electron (v5) for forked processes, node-pre-gyp assumed a Node process and returned a path to `node-v70-win32-x64` which didn't exist because the node version I use to `npm install node-sqlite3` is different from the node version that the forked process reports to node-pre-gyp. I *did* have `node-v67-win32-x64` in my `node_modules/sqlite3/lib/binding` directory.
- Thus, although electron-builder correctly created `electron-v5.0-win32-x64` in `node_modules/sqlite3/lib/binding`, node-pre-gyp returned `node-v70-win32-x64` to node-sqlite3 and of course the module couldn't be found. The final piece was therefore to update to Electron v6 which reports the Electron version to forked processes, allowing node-pre-gyp to detect an electron process and return the correct path to the binary that electron-builder created, in this case `node_modules/sqlite3/lib/binding/electron-v6.0-win32-x64`.

Answer (score 0):

Just my two cents since these issues can be very time consuming: I am also forking a process which depends on sqlite3 from an electron app.

The way I have it set up and working is as follows (Electron v8.0.1):

There are two project folders, "parent" and "child". Parent is the electron project with main and renderer code.

In the parent:

1. Include as a `devDependency: electron-builder`
2. Add as a postinstall script `electron-builder install-app-deps`
3. If this is immediately after adding electron-builder, run postinstall manually. In the future it's run automatically after `npm i`

This should take care rebuilding sqlite3 against electron.

Now to get the child process to use that lib.

1. The child process development depends on sqlite too, so just install that locally
2. I bundle all my js files using webpack
3. To have webpack working for the backend, I add

```
externals: {
    sqlite3: 'commonjs sqlite3'
  },
```

(In this way webpack doesn't attempt to bundle in sqlite3, which doesn't work with native modules.

Back in the parent:

I. Say the output bundle is called "child.js", copy it to the parent folder, and add it to the `files` attribute in the "electron-builder.json" file, e.g. `files: ["!*.log", "!doc", ..., "child.js"]`. Like this the child is added into the asar archive at the app's root. Don't use electron-builder's `extraFiles`/`extraResources` and try to fork the child like that, your child won't find sqlite3.

II. In the app's "main.ts" file, launch the child as

```
fork(path.resolve(app.getAppPath(), 'child.js')
```

This should do it, hope it's helpful to anybody.