# Electron app renderer process is crashing while loading new html page

Tags: node.js, electron, node-sqlite3

I am new to Electron.js and Node.js. I am building a simple inventory desktop app using Electron.js using sqlite3 module. My app crashes while the BrowserWindow is loading a new html page. Ctrl+R reload solves it.

Eg. In main.js (IPCMain), I do:

```
    win = new BrowserWindow({
        width: 1000,
        height: 800,
        webPreferences: {
            nodeIntegration: true
        }
    });

    win.loadFile(appPath+'/src/html/index.html');
```

This loads the page alright. When I click on a link on the page to /src/html/groups.html, the Window renders a blank screen (crashes?). When I refresh (Ctrl+R), the page renders alright! This happens to each and every link. First, it crashes, and then, Ctrl+R solves it!

I tried to handle unhandled exception like so (renderer process)...

```
window.onerror = function(error, url, line) {
    ipcRenderer.send('error-in-window', error);
};
```

and console.log it in the main process like this:

```
ipcMain.on('error-in-window', function(event, data) {
    console.log(data);
});
```

but it didn't get caught. So I tried this in the main process and it worked...

```
    win.webContents.on('crashed', (e) => {
        console.log(e);
    });
```

This is the log that I get:

```
{
  preventDefault: [Function: preventDefault],
  sender: WebContents {
    webContents: [Circular],
    history: [
      'file:///D:/My%20Drive/dev/simple_inventory/src/html/index.html',
      'file:///D:/My%20Drive/dev/simple_inventory/src/html/groups.html'
    ],
    currentIndex: 1,
    pendingIndex: -1,
    inPageIndex: -1,
    _events: [Object: null prototype] {
      'navigation-entry-committed': [Function],
      '-ipc-message': [Function],
      '-ipc-invoke': [Function],
      '-ipc-message-sync': [Function],
      '-ipc-ports': [Function],
      'pepper-context-menu': [Function],
      crashed: [Array],
      'render-process-gone': [Function],
      'devtools-reload-page': [Function],
      '-new-window': [Function],
      '-add-new-contents': [Function],
      login: [Function],
      move: [Function],
      activate: [Function],
      'page-title-updated': [Function],
      'render-view-deleted': [Array]
    },
    _eventsCount: 16,
    _maxListeners: 0,
    browserWindowOptions: { width: 1000, height: 800, webPreferences: [Object] }
  }
}
```

I tried on both Ubuntu as well as Windows 10. I get the same error. I think the problem is with sqlite3 module, because when I comment out the db queries, it works alright!

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

**Edit**: **Adding source code of groups.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
      <meta charset = "UTF-8">
      <title>Simple Inventory</title>

      <!-- Bootstrap loading -->
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="../lib/bootstrap-4.0.0/dist/css/bootstrap.css" />
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/style.css" />

      <!-- Font Awesome JS -->
      <script defer src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.13/js/solid.js" integrity="sha384-tzzSw1/Vo+0N5UhStP3bvwWPq+uvzCMfrN1fEFe+xBmv1C/AtVX5K0uZtmcHitFZ" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
      <script defer src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.13/js/fontawesome.js" integrity="sha384-6OIrr52G08NpOFSZdxxz1xdNSndlD4vdcf/q2myIUVO0VsqaGHJsB0RaBE01VTOY" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
      
   </head>
   
    <body>

        <div class="wrapper">
            <!-- Sidebar -->
            <nav id="sidebar">
                <div class="sidebar-header">
                    <h3>Simple Inventory</h3>
                </div>

                <div id="menuHolder">
                </div>
            </nav>

            <div id="content" style="width:100%">
                <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
                    <div class="container-fluid">
                        <button type="button" id="sidebarCollapse" class="btn btn-secondary">
                            <i class="fas fa-align-left"></i>
                            <span>Menu</span>
                        </button>
                    </div>
                </nav>
                <nav aria-label="breadcrumb">
                    <ol class="breadcrumb">
                        <li class="breadcrumb-item"><a href="./index.html">Home</a></li>
                        <li class="breadcrumb-item">Master</li>
                        <li class="breadcrumb-item active" aria-current="page">Groups</li>
                    </ol>
                </nav>

                <div class="container-fluid" style="padding:20px;" id="contentDiv">

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <!-- Bootstrap and jQuery loading -->
        <script src="../lib/jquery-3.5.1/jquery-3.5.1.min.js" onload="window.$ = window.jQuery = module.exports;"></script>
        <script src="../lib/bootstrap-4.0.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.js"></script>
        <script src="../js/popper.min.js"></script>
        <script src="../js/groups.js"></script>
   </body>
</html>
```

**groups.js (which is actually causing the crash)**

```
const remote = require('electron').remote;
const ipcRenderer = require('electron').ipcRenderer;
const app = remote.app;

const commonModule = require('../../src/modules/commonModule.js');
const inventoryModule = require('../../src/modules/inventoryModule.js');

$(document).ready(()=>{

    // Load side menu
    commonModule.loadSideMenu('groups', (err, html)=>{
        $('#menuHolder').html(html);
    });

    inventoryModule.getGroups((err, result) => {
        if(err) {
            $('#contentDiv').html('Error fetching data!');
            console.log(err);
        } else {
            let resultHTML = `<table class="table table-sm table-light table-hover">
                                <thead>
                                    <tr>
                                        <th>S.No.</th>
                                        <th>Name</th>
                                    </tr>
                                </thead>
                                <tbody>`;

            let count = 0;
            for(let key in result) {
                if(result[key].id) {
                    count++;
                    resultHTML += `<tr class="groupRow clickable" id="row_${result[key].id}">
                                        <td>${count}</td>
                                        <td>${result[key].name}</td>
                                    </tr>`;
                }
            }
            resultHTML += `</tbody>
                    </table>`;
            resultHTML += `<br />
                            <div class="container text-center">
                                <button class="btn btn-secondary" onclick="newGroup()">New Group</button>
                            </div>`;
            $('#contentDiv').html(resultHTML);
        }
    })
});

$(document).on("click","tr.groupRow", function(e){
    let groupID = commonModule.getRowID(e);
    ipcRenderer.send('open-new-window', 'groupsDialog.html', [`id=${groupID}`], 800, 600);
});

window.onerror = function(error, url, line) {
    ipcRenderer.send('error-in-window', error);
};

function newGroup() {
    ipcRenderer.send('open-new-window', 'groupsDialogNew.html', [], 800, 600);
}
```

Comment: Since you didn't include the source code of the page that is actually causing the crash, the only thing we can do is guesswork. Please edit your question to include the source code (HTML and JavaScript, if any) of `/src/html/groups.html`

Comment: @AlexanderLeithner I have updated the question to include the source code

Answer (score 1):

This was crashing the app. `const sqlite3 = require('sqlite3').verbose();`

Commenting out the line removes the functionality, but not causing the renderer to crash. The crash had something to do with `node-pre-gyp`:

[Electron crashes when requiring sqlite3 native module in forked process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52897950/electron-crashes-when-requiring-sqlite3-native-module-in-forked-process)

I had used electron 9.1.1 and sqlite3 5.0.0. But, from the sqlite3 npm page (https://www.npmjs.com/package/sqlite3),

> The sqlite3 module works with
> Node.js v11.x, v12.x, v13.x and v14.x.
> Electron v6.0.x, v6.1.x, v7.0.x, v7.1.x, v8.0.x, v8.1.x and v8.2.x

I changed my electron version to 8.2.0 and it works fine now.